# How create JSON string with field name

Tags: javascript, json

In my application, Asp web service returns JSON with object name called `'d'` so I access that `'d'` object the in the application as follows,

[image]

```
GetBranchOrRegionDataSourceSuccess: function (result, status, init) {
    "use strict";
    var regions = JSON.parse(result.d);
}
```

I called this function inside the Ajax success call.

Now the problem is I have Jquery function called `searchLocations`, Inside that function, I need to call this function. and need to pass the parameters.

I tried like this,

```
var jsonResult = JSON.stringify({'d':result});
  this.GetBranchOrRegionDataSourceSuccess(jsonResult,"Success", true); //here I need to call the function
```

this is my complete function.

```
function searchName(prov,tree) {
  var result = [];

  let searchKey = new RegExp(prov, "i");

  var objects = JSON.parse(json);
  for (obj of objects) {
    if (obj.Name.match(searchKey)) {

      result.push(obj); 

    } else {
      var toAdd = {"Id": obj.Id, "Name": obj.Name, "Branches": []};
      for (branch of obj.Branches) {
        if (branch.Name.match(searchKey)) {
          toAdd.Branches.push(branch);
        }
      }
      if (toAdd.Branches.length) {
        result.push(toAdd);
      }
    }
  }

  var jsonResult = JSON.stringify({'d':result});
  this.GetBranchOrRegionDataSourceSuccess(jsonResult,"Success", true); //here I need to call the function

}
```

But it makes error inside `GetBranchOrRegionDataSourceSuccess` on this line `var regions = JSON.parse(result.d);` How can I pass the result with `'d'` object name

Comment: FYI [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is faster than `String.prototype.match()` if you're just checking

Comment: @Phil You mean I should need to replace all the `match` functions with `test()` ?

Comment: Only if you want to and it would be like `if(searchKey.test(branch.Name))`

Comment: @Phil Okay sir Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetBranchOrRegionDataSourceSuccess` is expecting an [**object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) with property `d`.

The `d` property value needs to be a JSON string (which it will parse).

You want

```js
let jsonResult = { d: JSON.stringify(result) }
this.GetBranchOrRegionDataSourceSuccess(jsonResult, 'Success', true)
```